# Improvement of stddev function

Tags: python, pandas

I just wrote a function to calculate the standard-deviation of one specific column of a pandas dataframe. I just wanted to ask, if there is a way to do this more efficient than I did it here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import astropy
from astropy.table import QTable, Table, Column
from astropy import units as u
import random


def std_dev(Dataframe, column, nb_rows, av):
    DF = Dataframe
    calc = []

    for x in DF[column].tolist():
        r = (x - av)**2
        calc.append(r)

    #calculating sum over calc
    R = sum(calc)
    return (R / (nb_rows - 1))**(1 / 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample = Table({
        'row':
        np.array([round(random.uniform(3300, 3700), 2) for i in 
        range(20)])
    })
    df = sample.to_pandas()
    a = std_dev(df, 'row', 20, 3500)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assuming the code works, this would be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, the code does work. thanks for the advice! I will post the question there and delete it here.